# Transforming rows having dynamic dates into columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, pivot-table, unpivot

Need to convert this:

```
DATE            VALUE
18-DEC-15   2877544
17-DEC-15   2974276
16-DEC-15   4862020
```

into

```
18-DEC-15   17-DEC-15   16-DEC-15
2877544     2974276     4862020
```

The dates are updated everyday and I need to pick only the latest 3 dates and convert them into columns with the corresponding values below.
I tried using Pivots but I'm able to create the column headers dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Conditional Aggregate` to pivot the data

```
select MAX(case when "DATE" = '18-DEC-15' then VALUE END) as '18-DEC-15',
       MAX(case when "DATE" = '17-DEC-15' then VALUE END) as '17-DEC-15',
       MAX(case when "DATE" = '16-DEC-15' then VALUE END) as '16-DEC-15'
from yourtable
```

**Note :** since dates are unknown, you need to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`

Comment: Could you please elaborate how EXECUTE IMMEDIATE functionality can be used here ? Also on try your above mentioned query I got an error which says 'FROM keyword not found where expected'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WITH pivot_data AS (
            select date, value from table)
    SELECT *
    FROM   pivot_data
    PIVOT (
              max(value)        --<-- pivot_clause
          FOR table --<-- pivot_for_clause


);
```

Answer (score 0):

A SQL query has well-defined column names, so for variable column names you need dynamic SQL.  But, you can do what you want with fixed names:

```
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) as MostRecentDay,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then value end) as SecondMostRecentDay,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then value end) as ThirdMostRecentDay
from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

You could even add three columns specifying the date values:

```
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) as MostRecentDay,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then value end) as SecondMostRecentDay,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then value end) as ThirdMostRecentDay,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then date end) as MostRecentDate,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then date end) as SecondMostRecentDate,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then date end) as ThirdMostRecentDate           
from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```